# What are Tom Banks's arguments against a QFT of QG cont..?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity

[What are Tom Banks's arguments against a QFT of quantum gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422917/)

I do not feel that the answer given here includes all of his arguments. The answer given in the other question only included his argument for BH entropy, but as you can see by reading pages 1-9 in the link paper, he give lots of arguments that I would like to have an explanation to (on a laymen level).

Can someone go through each of the arguments he gives and just give a detailed explanation of what he is saying?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4001

Comment: @JMac No it isn't

Comment: What is different about this question, besides referencing the answer in the previous one?

Comment: If you're just looking for a better answer, this would definitely be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @JMac you're right, I am looking for a more complete answer. And I think that reposting this question is the best way to get a better answer

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8974/re-asking-a-duplicate-question It's not the right approach here, especially when it's your own question from only a day ago.